# Is there a way to return a string with a variable in it?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass in a variable to be used in a string, but is it possible to keep that variable so that I can change it later?

```
var blah = function(name){
    return "hello" +name;
}
var thisName = blah('james');
name+="  williams";
```

So thisName was = "hello james", but I want thisName to change to "hello james williams" when I change name.

Comment: You define `thisName` and append to `name`... how do you think that would work?

Comment: Variables have independent values.  When you change the value of one variable, that doesn't change the value of any other variable.  There's no way to set things up so that one variable automatically changes when another changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to alter `name` from outside of the `function`. Named arguments like it only *exist* within the `function`'s block -- `{` to `}`.

And, `thisName` only knows the resulting `'hello james'`, anyways. It doesn't *remember* that it came from evaluating `'hello ' + name`. So, even if you could change `name`, doing so wouldn't automatically be reflected by `thisName`.

So, if you want to alter `thisName`, you can either do so directly:

```
var thisName = blah('james');
thisName += ' williams';
```

Or keep a separate `name` (each scope can have its own) and reset `thisName` to the result of calling `blah(name)` again:

```
var name = 'james';
var thisName = blah(name);

name += ' williams';
thisName = blah(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
var blah = function(name){
    return "hello " + name;
}
var thisName = blah('james');
thisName += " williams";
```